# Getting dates from google analytics API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get the individual dates from data retrieved from the google analytics api.
I am trying to emulate what the google analytics app does.

So for example the google analytics app has a line chart and if the date range is April 20-25 and the total users is 4, it shows that there were 2 users on the 22nd and 2 on the 27th. etc...

But when I retrieve data using the api such as

```
 const url = `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${propertyId}:runReport`;

  const requestBody = {
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'activeUsers',
      },
      {
        name: 'bounceRate',
      },
      {
        name: 'averageSessionDuration',
      },
      {
        name: 'engagedSessions',
      },
      {
        name: 'eventCount',
      },
      {
        name: 'eventsPerSession',
      },
      {
        name: 'screenPageViewsPerSession',
      },
      {
        name: 'sessions',
      },
      {
        name: 'sessionsPerUser',
      },
      { name: 'totalUsers' },
    ],
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        name: 'date_range',
      },
    ],
  };
 const response = await axios.post(url, requestBody, requestOptions);
```

The data returns this

```
{
    "metricHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "activeUsers",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
            "name": "bounceRate",
            "type": "TYPE_FLOAT"
        },
        {
            "name": "averageSessionDuration",
            "type": "TYPE_SECONDS"
        },
        {
            "name": "engagedSessions",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
            "name": "eventCount",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
            "name": "eventsPerSession",
            "type": "TYPE_FLOAT"
        },
        {
            "name": "screenPageViewsPerSession",
            "type": "TYPE_FLOAT"
        },
        {
            "name": "sessions",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
            "name": "sessionsPerUser",
            "type": "TYPE_FLOAT"
        },
        {
            "name": "totalUsers",
            "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "metricValues": [
                {
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "0.6"
                },
                {
                    "value": "29.2088052"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "45"
                },
                {
                    "value": "9"
                },
                {
                    "value": "4.2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "5"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1.25"
                },
                {
                    "value": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rowCount": 1,
    "metadata": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "timeZone": "Etc/GMT-3"
    },
    "kind": "analyticsData#runReport"
}
```

So it just shows totals without showing explicitly when the users were active.

Am I missing a parameter or is it simply not possible to get those dates?

By the way I am trying to fetch the new GA4 tracking id's.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your **requestBody** I see that you are requesting the metrics only, for this reason you are getting the aggregated data for the entire selected period.

You should also enter the `date` dimension to have the breakdown of values by date in the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michele Pisani for answering the question.

I have found a very useful website that shows which values are available

https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/

And yes I needed to add this

```
 dimensions: [
      {
        name: 'date',
      },
    ],
```

To my request body.

Thanks!